# Dynamically calculate a div width

Tags: javascript

Here are sample divisions:

```css
#grandparent {
  width: 100px;
}
#parent {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
.child {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">

  <div id="parent">

    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>
    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>
    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>
    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>
    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>
    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>
    <div class="child">1000000000000000000000000</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The `<div class="child">` width value is always 10 pixels less than `<div id="parent">` width value. How can it be calculated so any width value is given to `<div id="parent">`, its child gets 10 pixels less than that?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Mike

Comment: More clarification: For the overflow:hidden to work poperly cross browser, I need to add a width value, for example: .child {overflow:hidden; margin-left:10px; width:73px;}. But I'd like it to be calculated and added to its style dynamically. For example if I set <div id="parent"> width value to 83px, the child gets width:73px in its style automatically.

Answer (score 8):

With jQuery, this is very easy. Just subtract 10 from `what.innerWidth()` Here:

```
$(".child").css('width', $('#parent').innerWidth()-10);
```

You could also do it like this:

```
$(".child").each(function(){
    $(this).css('width', $(this).parent().innerWidth()-10);
});
```

-Which means you could have more than one parent, without having to know the `id`.

## Normal JS

You can use the `clientWidth` property of an HTML element object. Like this:

```
var targetParent = document.getElementById('parent'); // or whatever
var targets = targetParent.getElementsByClassName('child');
for(var i=0;i<targets.length;i++) targets[i].parentNode.style.width = targets[i].clientWidth - 10;
```

Hope this helps! - Tanner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for the JavaScript solution.

Comment: Technically jQuery IS javascript

Comment: @Rain Lover: jQuery *is* javascript. Just a javascript framework. I really don't know any other way of doing it.

Comment: @Rain Lover: Edited my answer, please see.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, Tanner!

Comment: I tried this. I had a parent division with three children. I was using an automatic width for the left and right division and tried to use your method to subtract their widths from the width of the parent to get a width for the middle division. 
I used your jQuery method.
The only problem is that the value is correct but I have to subtract 4 more pixels to get it to fit. Is the some kind of limitation in the code?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with calc

```
      width: -webkit-calc(50% - 7px) !important;
      width: -moz-calc(50% - 7px) !important;
      width: calc(50% - 7px) !important;
```

More info and examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this css for parent:

```
#parent {
 overflow:auto; height:100px;
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm after. I'd like to dynamically add width to the child style based on its parent width.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the selectors are for in CSS:

```
#parent.div {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The child already has a margin. For the overflow:hidden to work cross browser, I need to add a width value, for example: .child {overflow:hidden; margin-left:10px; width:73px;}. But it needs to be calculated and added to its style dynamically.